# Embedded C++ Class interaction

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interaction

I'm continuing with a game for an embedded microcontroller (Arduino), and I have a question on class interaction -- this question continues from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191438/embedded-c-polymorphism-and-inheritance) and I have based my code on the suggestion of sheddenizen (see response to the given link in 'here'):

I have three classes that inherit from a base class-

(i)   *class Sprite* - (bass class) has a bitmap shape and (x,y) position on an LCD

(ii)  *class Missile : public Sprite* - has a specific shape, (x,y) and also takes a obj

(iii) *class Alien : public Sprite*  - has specific shape and (x,y)

(iv)  *class Player : public Sprite* - ""

They all have different (virtual) method of moving and are shown on the LCD:

[image]

**My streamlined code is below - specifically, I only want the missile to fire under certain conditions: when missile is created it takes an objects (x,y) value, how can I access a passed objects value within an inherited class?**

```
// Bass class - has a form/shape, x and y position 
// also has a method of moving, though its not defined what this is  
class Sprite
{
  public:
    Sprite(unsigned char * const spacePtrIn, unsigned int xInit, unsigned int yInit);
    virtual void Move() = 0;
    void Render() { display.drawBitmap(x,y, spacePtr, 5, 6, BLACK); }
    unsigned int X() const { return x; } 
    unsigned int Y() const { return y; }
  protected:
    unsigned char *spacePtr;
    unsigned int x, y;
};

// Sprite constructor
Sprite::Sprite(unsigned char * const spacePtrIn, unsigned int xInit, unsigned int yInit)
{
  x = xInit;
  y = yInit;
  spacePtr = spacePtrIn;
}

/*****************************************************************************************/
// Derived class "Missile", also a sprite and has a specific form/shape, and specific (x,y) derived from input sprite
// also has a simple way of moving
class Missile : public Sprite
{
public:
   Missile(Sprite const &launchPoint): Sprite(&spaceMissile[0], launchPoint.X(), launchPoint.Y()) {}
   virtual void Move();
};

void Missile::Move()
{
  // Here - how to access launchPoint.X() and launchPoint.Y() to check for 
  // "fire conditions" 
  y++;
  Render();
}


// create objects
Player HERO;
Alien MONSTER;
Missile FIRE(MONSTER);

// moving objects 
HERO.Move(); 
MONSTER.Move();
FIRE.Move();
```

Comment: You ask how to access a variable in one function that has been passed to another function. That's not possible: are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Missile` is a subclass of `Sprite` you can access `Sprite::x` and `Sprite::y` as if they were members of Missile. That is by simply writing `x` (or `this->x` if you insist).

The `launchpoint` reference that you got in the constructor is gone by now, so your `Missile::Move` memfunction cannot access it any more.

If in the meantime the members `x` and `y` changed, but you want the *original* value, you can either save a reference to `launchpoint` (which might be dangerous, it is destroyed) or you have to keep a copy of the original coordinates.

Comment: Thanks bitmask, to make sure I understand --  I'd like to access the (passed) sprite's x and not the missile's x: float temp = Sprite::x; // float = this->x

Comment: @JakeFrench: Since there is only one `x` in the scope of the `Move` member function, all of these do the same thing: `x`, `this->x`, `Sprite::x`, `this->Sprite::x`. At the moment you are in the scope of `Move`, you cannot access the `launchpoint` object any more. If you need that information, you have to store it separately while you're still *in the constructor*.