# C++ double pointer member access

Tags: c++, pointers, double, member

C++ (Arduino wrapper) question: I'm writing a shoot em up game on an Arduino which has a LCD connected -

I have a base class (`Sprite`), and from this other classes are derived - `Alien`, `Missile` and `Player`. The constructor of the Alien class also has private member `pMissile` (a pointer to a `Missile` class) - 'an object within an object' would be a way to describe this I think.
**[when an `Alien` fires a missile, it passes its own (x,y) coordinates to the missile, and the missile has its own method of moving starting from the `Alien`'s coordinates]**

My question is: How can I access the coordinates of the missile through the `Alien` object?
Streamlined code is below and I have also drawn a representation of the classes:

```
// Bass class - has a form/shape, x and y position  
class Sprite
{
  public:
    Sprite(unsigned char * const spacePtrIn, unsigned int xInit, unsigned int yInit);
    virtual void Move() = 0;
    void Render() { display.drawBitmap(x,y, spacePtr, 5, 6, BLACK); }
    unsigned int getX()    const { return x; } 
    unsigned int getY()    const { return y; }
  protected:
    unsigned char *spacePtr;
    unsigned int x, y;
};


// Derived class "Missile", also a sprite and has a specific form/shape, and specific (x,y) derived from input sprite
class Missile : public Sprite
{
public:
   Missile(): Sprite(&spaceMissile[0], 0, 0) {}
   virtual void Move();  // its own method of moving
};

// Derived class "Alien" - has a specific form/shape, and specific (x,y) position
class Alien : public Sprite
{
public:
   Alien(); 
   virtual void Move();   // its own method of moving
private:
   Missile *pMissile;
};

Alien::Alien(): Sprite(&spaceAlien[0], random(5, 75), random(4, 10))
{
  Missile MissileArray[MaxAmmoSize];
  pMissile = &MissileArray[0];
}


void Alien::Move()
{ 
  if( random(10) % 2 == 0 )
    x += 1;
  if( random(10) % 3 == 0 )
    y += 1;

  if( (pMissile != NULL) && (random(10) == 1) )
  {
    pMissile->setCoord(x, y);
    pMissile->Move();  // move the missile   
    pMissile++;        // move onto the next missile in the array
  }
  Render();
}

/*****************************************************************************************/
Alien MONSTER;
Player HERO;
Alien *pMONSTER = &MONSTER;

void loop()
{
  display.clearDisplay();
  MONSTER.Move();
  HERO.Move(); 
  pMONSTER->getX(); // this is x location of MONSTER
  **// how does pMONSTER access pMissile(x,y) within MONSTER.** 
  delay(100);
  display.display();
}
```

[image]

[Embedded C++ Class interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349001/embedded-c-class-interaction/19349049#19349049)

Comment: The short answer is "It doesn't."  You either need to provide an interface in Alien that lets you get a copy of pMissile, or an interface that forwards requests to it.  Or, take pMissile out of Alien and just treat it on an equal footing to your other entities.

Comment: A side note: alien etc being subclasses of sprite does not sound very good design. Alien etc *have* a sprite (perhaps several) associated with them, but they are game objects. Sounds like composition would be better than inheritance. Then it might be easier to also figure out how to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to add a getter function to Alien:

```
class Alien {
public:
    Missile* getMissile() { return pMissile; }
}
```

To use it:

```
Alien* a = getAlienFromSomewhere();
auto pMissile = a.GetMissile();
if (pMissile != NULL) {
    x = pMissile->getX();
    y = pMissile->getY();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you want to access your missile position through the alien to test the collision with your hero entity, but if you need to keep the track of your missiles you should not "walk" with your pointer to the next missile as shown in the `Alien::Move()`. Doing this you will lose the reference of the beginning of the array.

IMHO, I would do something like this in your alien class:

```
// Bass class - has a form/shape, x and y position  
class Sprite
{
  public:
    Sprite(unsigned char * const spacePtrIn, unsigned int xInit, unsigned int yInit);
    virtual void Move() = 0;
    void Render() { display.drawBitmap(x,y, spacePtr, 5, 6, BLACK); }
    unsigned int& getX()    const { return x; } 
    unsigned int& getY()    const { return y; }
  protected:
    unsigned char *spacePtr;
    unsigned int x, y;
};


// Derived class "Missile", also a sprite and has a specific form/shape, and specific (x,y) derived from input sprite
class Missile : public Sprite
{
public:
   Missile(): Sprite(&spaceMissile[0], 0, 0) {}
   virtual void Move();  // its own method of moving
};

// Derived class "Alien" - has a specific form/shape, and specific (x,y) position
class Alien : public Sprite
{
public:
   Alien(); 
   ~Alien(); // a destructor to cleanup your missiles - arduino have almost no memory to handle leaks ;-) 
   virtual void Move();   // its own method of moving

   inline Missile& getMissile(unsigned char n) { return pMissile[n];          }
   inline Missile& operator[](unsigned char n) { return getMissile(n);        }
   inline unsigned int& getX(unsigned char n)  { return getMissile(n).getX(); }
   inline unsigned int& getY(unsigned char n)  { return getMissile(n).getY(); }

private:
   Missile *pMissile;
   // adding the code to handle the count
   unsigned char missileCount;
};

Alien::Alien(): 
  Sprite(&spaceAlien[0], random(5, 75), random(4, 10)),
  missileCount(0)
{
  // this way of allocation creates a local object that is destroyed by the end of this scope
  //Missile MissileArray[MaxAmmoSize];
  //pMissile = &MissileArray[0];

  // so you should do somethin like this
  pMissile = new Missile[MaxAmmoSize];
}

Alien()::~Alien()
{
  delete[] pMissile;
}

void Alien::Move()
{ 
  if( random(10) % 2 == 0 )
    x += 1;
  if( random(10) % 3 == 0 )
    y += 1;

  if( (pMissile != NULL) && (random(10) == 1) )
  {
    // my proposal to fire it up
    Missile& missile = pMissile[missileCount];
    missile->setCoord(x, y);
    missile->Move();  // move the missile   
    missileCount++;   // move onto the next missile in the array
  }
  Render();
}
```

Using the code like this you could access the locations of your missiles by using:

```
MONSTER.getX(0) += 1;
MONSTER[0].getY() +=1;
MONSTER.getMissile(1).getX() = 10;
```

To have some clarity I recommend also the refactoring of the `getX()` and `getY()` methods to `x()` and `y()`, since they are returning references to the class contents (and doing this, you should also rename your `x` and `y` members to something else, or you can get crazy with name conflicts).